# Named parameterized SQL queries in Java

Tags: java, sql

From poking around in `PreparedStatement`, it appears that parameterizing SQL statements only allows the developer to specify positional arguments using `?` and `PreparedStatement.setX(index, value)`:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from something where id = ?;");
statement.setString(1, '5');
```

Is there  a way to supply named parameters to prepared statements like this:

```
ParameterizedStatement statement = connection.parameterizeStatement(
    "select * from something where id = $id;");
statement.setString("id", "5");
```

Does something exist for this in Java?

Comment: Not in the JDBC api, but yes in JDBC wrapper libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the base JDK, but this sounds like the MyBatis [SQL Builder](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) Class.

For example,

```
// Anonymous inner class
public String deletePersonSql() {
  return new SQL() {{
    DELETE_FROM("USER");
    WHERE("ID = ${id}");
  }}.toString();
}

// Builder / Fluent style
public String insertPersonSql() {
  String sql = new SQL()
    .INSERT_INTO("USER");
    .VALUES("ID, FIRST_NAME", "${id}, ${firstName}")
    .VALUES("LAST_NAME", "${lastName}")
    .toString(); 
  return sql;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JPA queries can use named parameters, example:

```
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Magazine x WHERE x.title = :titleParam and x.price > :priceParam");
q.setParameter("titleParam", "JDJ");
q.setParameter("priceParam", 5.0);
List<Magazine> results = (List<Magazine>) q.getResultList();
```